# Нужно перевернуть многомерный массив по часовой стрелке

Tags: python

Нужно перевернуть многомерный массив по часовой стрелке. Пока сделал только

```
N = int(input());
Arr = [0]*N;
newArr = [0]*N;
for i in range(N):
    Arr[i] = [0] * N;
    newArr[i] = [0] * N;
for j in range(N):
    num = int(input());
    Arr[j][num-1] = Arr[j][num-1] + 1;
```

N - длина массива  и их кол-во (одинаковое)
теперь хочу циклом перекласть соответственно в новый массив, но ума не хватает, поможете?
массив многомерный, каждый из подмассивов одинаковой длинны, содержащий нули и одну единицу типа

```
[
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
]
```

надо получить

```
[
[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,0]
]
```

Comment: а зачем писать "Вопрос в названии", когда правильнее его было бы в текст из названия скопировать?

Comment: `надо получить` - у вас то что было и то что стало - одинаково, так что получить надо? вы бы вопрос поаккуратнее составили бы

Comment: @Zhihar исправил

Comment: Тут просто надо тщательно подумать над формулой пересчёта индексов, а так то цикл в цикле перебор, ничего сложного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy

matrix = numpy.array([[1,0,2], [0,0,0], [4,0,3]])

print(numpy.rot90(matrix, 3))
```

в итоге будет поворот по часовой

```
 [[1 0 2]
  [0 0 0]
  [4 0 3]]
 
 [[4 0 1]
  [0 0 0]
  [3 0 2]]
```